# Cannot run Laravel migration on Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration, laravel-migrations

I have been trying to run migration since yesterday but database connection is preventing it
Note: I can access the database very well from other projects. This only happens with laravel on homestead. Here is the output of the php artisan migrate command:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'abdellah'@'192.168.10.10' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema = furbook and table_name
>   = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

This is my .env database config

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=furbook
DB_USERNAME=abdellah
DB_PASSWORD=bonjour1
```

And this is the database.php file

```
      'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'furbook'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'abdellah'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'bonjour1'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

I am running on Homestead environment.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: @aynber I can access the database from other projects. Only Laravel on homestead refuses to connect.

Comment: This might be stupid, but are you sure you're running the migrate command inside the Homestead virtual box? I mean after `vagrant ssh`?

Comment: @Saly3301 yes I have ssh into the box and I am running from the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run the migration successfully by setting the DB username to homestead and DB password to secret.

```
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure everything is spelled correctly?

The only other thing I can think of is adding an extra 0 at the end of the port (`DB_PORT=33060`).

It's weird but I had a fresh Laravel project using homestead and the only way I could access the DB artisan commands in the terminal was to add a 0 on the port but then I had to take it off again once accessing it through HTTP.

Comment: I just did. Do I have to create the database tables before running migration?

Comment: Yes you have to

Comment: You shouldn't have to. The idea of the migrations is to have full control of creating, updating and deleting everything to do with a table and its structure.

Comment: @LewisHayter okay I was being confused.

Comment: No problem! Did the additional 0 on the end of the port work for you?